# Mongoid 4 on Rails 3 compatability

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid, gemfile

Some of the new features in Mongoid 4 (4.0.0.alpha) are very useful to me, in particular, aliased attributes working in criteria.

For the time being, however, I'm stuck on Rails 3.2.

When I try to `bundle update mongoid` after specifying `4.0.0.alpha`, I encounter compatability issues on the `activemodel` gem:

```
mongoid (= 4.0.0.alpha1) ruby depends on
  activemodel (~> 4.0.0) ruby

rails (= 3.2.13) ruby depends on
  activemodel (3.2.13)
```

Is there anyway to use Mongoid 4 with Rails 3?

Comment: Have you managed to fix this issue?

Comment: @Alpesh I ended up just upgrading to Rails 4. Good luck!